# Arrays with Static Methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static

I am trying to manipulate two Arrays by using two different Static Methods

1. `double dot(double[]a, double[]b)`
2. `double[][] multiply(double[][]a, double[][]b)`.

I cant seem to figure out how to multiply the two arrays using static methods and output there values to the user I believe my Dot product method is good though. I know I need to use a return method for my multiplication method but im not sure how to represent this correctly

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class LibMatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] a = { 8, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1 };
        double[] b = { 9, 8, 4, 1, 4, 7 };
    }

    public static double dot(double[] a, double[] b) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            sum += a[i] * b[i];
        return sum;

    }

    public static double[][] multiply(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
        int n = 6;
        double[][] c = new double[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; i < n; i++)
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] * b[i][j];
        return a;

    }
}
```

Comment: The second method is for matrices (bidimensional arrays), but your "static arrays" are one-dimensional...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; can't you call the methods in `main`, reference the return values, and iterate over them?

Comment: `return a;` -> `return c;`

Comment: Also, `int n = 6;` -> `int n = a.length; assert n == 0 || (a[0].length == n && b.length == n && b[0].length == n);`

Comment: Changed the return a; to return c; in the method that is what I originally wrote I just changed it to try and get some type of output. So what you are saying is that my method of multiplication will not work because my arrays are one dimensional how can i make them 2-D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some corrections:

```
public class LibMatrixTests
{
   static class LibMatrix {
      public static double dot(double[] a, double[] b) {
         double sum = 0.0;
         for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            sum += a[i] * b[i];
         return sum;
      }
      public static double[][] mul( double[][] a, double[][] b ) {
         double[][] c = new double[a.length][a[0].length];
         for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
               c[i][j] = a[i][j] * b[i][j];
         return a;
      }
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      double[]   a = { 8, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1 };
      double[]   b = { 9, 8, 4, 1, 4, 7 };
      double[][] c = { a, b };
      double[][] d = { b, a };
      double     e = LibMatrix.dot( a, b );
      double[][] f = LibMatrix.mul( c, d );
      System.out.println( e );
      for( double[] g : f ) {
         for( double h : g ) {
            System.out.print( h + ", " );
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Outputs:

```
154.0
8.0, 5.0, 6.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 
9.0, 8.0, 4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 7.0,
```

Comment: Thank you so much thats exactly what I wanted the program to do now time to Trace and see how you did it:)

Comment: Use a diff utilities because you have misused the index i and j into for loops causing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 3):

Don't have enough rep to comment but your return value in the second method should be c

Test:

```
double [][] a = new double [6][6];
double [][] b = new double [6][6];

for(int i = 0; i< a.length;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< a.length;j++){
        a[i][j] = 3;
        b[i][j] = 2;
    }
}
d = multiply(a,b);
```

This returns a 6x6 matrix filled with 6s so your method is working correctly.

```
d = [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

in the multiply method, the second loop is wrong, j is always 0, and you should return c instead of a

try this

```
public static double[][] multiply(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
    int n = 6;
    double[][] c = new double[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] * b[i][j];
    return c;

}
```